# Kial estu spaco antaŭ "mil" sed ne antaŭ "cent" aŭ "dek"?

Tags: writing

La nombro 3539 estu skribata: *tri mil kvincent tridek naŭ*, kun spaco inter *tri* kaj *mil*. Kial?

Answer (score 5):

Mi ne certas, sed eble estas pro tio, ke *dek* kaj *cent* nur povas esti obligitaj per nombroj inter *du* ĝis *naŭ*, dum *mil* povas esti obligita per nombroj inter *du* kaj *naŭcent naŭdek naŭ*. Do kio okazos al la spacoj inter la obligintaj nombroj, t.e., la nombroj antaŭ *mil*: ***kvarcent tridek du*** mil? Ĉu ni metu strekon inter tiujn vortojn (**kvarcent-tridek-dumil**), aŭ tute meti ilin kunaj (**kvarcenttridekdumil**)? Aŭ nur alglui *du* al *mil*, sed lasi la aliajn apartaj (**kvarcent tridek dumil**)?
Oni ne vere skribus **dudek kvin cent**, kiel oni dirus en la angla ekzemple (“twenty-five hundred”), do tiu problemo ne okazus al *dek* kaj *cent*. La sama ja okazos al *miliono*, *miliardo*, ktp, do oni ne skribu **dumiliono** ekzemple.

Comment: [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/vortetoj/formoj.html#i-k81) priskribas similan kialon, do ĝi ja ŝajnas ĝusta.

Comment: @NeilRoberts Prave, mi fakte ne sciis. Dankon pro la ligilo!

Answer (score 3):

Mil estas kiel la punkto (aŭ spaco) en la nombro.

3.539 = 3 mil 539 = tri mil kvincent tridek naŭ

La afero fariĝas pli klara kiam ni rigardas pli grandajn nombrojn:

39.539 = 39 mil 359 = tridek naŭ mil kvincent tridek naŭ